# Unable to login and redirect in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am unable to login and redirect to home page using the custom login view (user_login) and AuthenticationForm. However, if i login using the admin page *(http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin)* and then reopen login page it automaticaly redirects to home page.

There is some issue related to authentication which is not getting done from my custom login page/view .I am unable to fix this or identify resolution based on answers provided online.

There is another issue regarding the URL it is showing as

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=FhHQjhGGgFDwcikpH9kl3OwQMcZisjWS2zvMHFGBU6KxGNWbamgago7FhtSs8MeN&username=admin&password=admin
```

However, Password and Username should not be showing in the URL if form method is post.

**URL**

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("signup/", views.user_signup, name="signup"),
path("login/", views.user_login, name="login"),
path("home/", views.homepage, name="home"),]
```

**Views**

```
def user_login(request):

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect("/home")
else:

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect("home")

            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name="socialapp/login.html",
        context={"login_form": form},
    )

def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request, template_name="socialapp/home.html")
```

**Login HTML**

```
        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" id="login-form"  method="post" class="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
    
            {% csrf_token %}
      
            {{ login_form|crispy }}
      
            <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800"  value="Submit">Login</button>
        </form>
```

**Home HTML**

```
{% block main %}
    <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen justify-center items-center ">
        <h1>Welcome to Home</h1>
    </div>
{% endblock main %}
```

**Settings**

```
LOGIN_URL = "/login"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/home"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check login in `else` part

```
def SigninView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is None:
            messages.error(request,'Please Enter Correct Credinatial')
            return redirect('/signin/')
        else:
            login(request,user)
            messages.info(request,'Login Successful')
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm()
            return render(request,'signin.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: This did not work for me either, there is seems some others issue maybe in my implementation of HTML for the from. I have attempted to debug it infact non of user_login() view if statements are getting called on submitting the request

Comment: Try with updated code

Comment: Figured out the issue, it was stupidly mentioned <form> twice in my HTML code that's why there was get request. By the way, i have implemented user_login using forms.Form in the application